# Concat data upwards based on value in another Column

Tags: excel, vba

I have data like in Column A and Column B. I would like to get data as in Column C.

is it possible to get the same by using VBA? I am not able to loop upwards.

Thank you in advance.

```
+----------+----------+----------+
| Column A | Column B | Column C |
+----------+----------+----------+
| a        |          |          |
| b        |          |          |
| c        |          |          |
| d        |        1 | a,b,c,d  |
| x        |          |          |
| y        |          |          |
| z        |        2 | y,z      |
| s        |          |          |
| d        |          |          |
| e        |        3 | s,d,e    |
+----------+----------+----------+
```

Comment: What happens to `x` in 2?

Comment: Look at `xldown` to finc the relevant row in column in B, then use `xlup` from that row to find the last place.  Then join(range(start:end),",")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub trst()

    Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long
    Dim str As String

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

         LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

         For i = 2 To LastRow

            If .Range("B" & i).Value = "" Then

                If str = "" Then
                    str = .Range("A" & i).Value
                Else
                    str = str & ", " & .Range("A" & i).Value
                End If

            Else

                .Range("C" & i).Value = str & ", " & .Range("A" & i).Value
                str = ""

            End If

         Next i

    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
Sub v()

Dim r As Excel.Range
Dim l As Long
Dim lRows As Long
Dim lNum As Long

Set r = Range("a1:b10")

l = 1

Do Until l > r.Rows.Count

    lNum = r.Cells(l, 2).End(xlDown).Row
    lRows = (lNum - l) + 1
    r.Cells(lNum, 3).Value = _
        Join(Application.Transpose(r.Cells(l, 1).Resize(lRows, 1)), ",")
    l = lNum + 1

Loop

End Sub
```